# Using JOINs to merge data from multiple tables to a unified table for export

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to export a report in csv format from data that is contained in three different tables. I made a temporary table using the data from one table. My idea was then to use two JOINs to add in the data from the others, and then once the temporary table is filled out using COPY to export it and then delete the table.

```
Table1
-id (primary key)
-data1
-data2 (foreign key for Table2)
-data3

Table2
-id (primary key, Table1.data2 matches with this)
-data1 (foreign key for Table3)
-data2

Table3
-id (primary key, Table2.data1 matches with this)
-data1
```

The final unified table would have the following:

```
-id
-table1.data1
-table1.data2
-table1.data3
-table2.data1
-table2.data2
-table3.data1
```

First I made a temporary table using the information I wanted from table1, as this table has most of the information for the report.

```
Database=# create temp table temp_table as select id,data1,data2,data3 from table1;
SELECT 71
```

Using a select showed the data in this new table.
Next, I tried to use a JOIN to join all the data from Table2 to Table1, using the matching keys.
`Database=# select * from table2 join temp_table on table2.id = temp_table.data2;`

The resulting console output showed success! It listed this combined table as expected. However, when using a select all statement on the temp table, it only showed the initial data fields it was populated with. It did not include the data from Table2 like I was shown in the console output. A quick select all on table2 showed no change, so I didn't flip flop them and accidentally copy temp_table to table2. I think I might be misunderstanding either the JOIN commands, or how they are properly used.
I am still very new to SQL, and I have made an honest attempt at searching for solutions but nothing I found seemed to be relevant or helpful. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and as I want to learn any explanations are also greatly appreciated :)
many thanks

edit:
sample data

```
table1
id  formalID    linkid  textdata
3   3           3       [blank]
9   13          9       [blank]
1   1           10      [blank]
35  38          [blank] “sample text”

table2
id  nameid  typetext
3   3       [blank]
9   9       “Alpha”
10  1       “Beta”

table3
id  nameText
3   “Sweet”
9   “Sour”
1   “Tangy”

end result:
formalID    nameText    typeText    textdata
3           “Sweet”     [blank]     [blank]
13          “Sour”      “Alpha”     [blank]
1           “Tangy”     “Beta”      [blank]
38          [blank]     [blank]     “sample text”
```

linkid would be table1.data2 from my initial post, that is the same as table2.id and nameid would be table2.data1 which is the same as table3.id
It is possible for entries to not have data in the other two, when this is the case they contain entries in 'textdata' but should still be included in the end result.

Comment: A `SELECT` never changes any tables contents. So yes, you're misunderstanding joins. It joins sets in the *result* of a `SELECT` together. But as `COPY` can take an arbitrary query your endeavor with the temporary table isn't needed anyways. To help you on the query more details are needed though. You should post sample data for all the tables and the desired result with that sample data. Please [edit] your question to do so.

Comment: Oh okay so because I used a SELECT with the JOIN, it was only going to display the output. If I wanted to merge the tables that would be another command like UPDATE? It seemed like UPDATE required both tables to have the columns already, so for example it isn't possible to add table2.typetext to table1 using the UPDATE JOIN? 
I did not know COPY can use anything other than a table, I must have misunderstood the documentation for that. Not needing to create a temporary table is great!

Answer (score 0):

The following should output all your data:

```
    SELECT t1.data1, t1.data3, t2.data2 as t2_data, t3.data1 as t3_data
    FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.data2 = t2.id
    LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.data1 = t3.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `COPY` command with a query directly. No need for a `TEMP TABLE`.

**Note:** The directory in which you intend to export to must allow write privileges to the `postgres` user.

Try the following:

```
COPY 
(   SELECT t1.id
         , t1.data1
         , t1.data2
         , t1.data3
         , t2.data1
         , t2.data2
         , t3.data1
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.d2 = t2.id
    LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.d1 = t3.id
)
TO 'path/to/filename'
WITH FORMAT CSV
```

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have it solved, you just need to set up your join statements. Your code should look like the following:

```
SELECT
table1.id,
table1.data1,
table1.data2,
table1.data3,
table2.data1,
table2.data2,
table3.data1
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.data2 = table2.id
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.data1 = table3.id
```

You can also add conditions to the individual JOIN statements if needed. Example:

```
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.data2 = table2.id
AND <condition>
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.data1 = table3.id
AND <condition>
```

Also, you don't need to use a temp table for this query.

Comment: So in this case, to export the result the command would be
```
COPY
SELECT
table1.id,
table1.data1,
table1.data2,
table1.data3,
table2.data1,
table2.data2,
table3.data1
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.data2 = table2.id
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.data1 = table3.id
TO '/path/for/file'
WITH FORMAT CSV
```

Answer (score 0):

With the given sample data

```
  SELECT t1.formalid,
         t3.nametext,
         t2.typetext,
         t1.textdata
         FROM table1 t1
              LEFT JOIN table2 t2
                        ON t2.nameid = t1.id
              LEFT JOIN table2 t3
                        ON t3.id = t1.id;
```

would get you the expected result. The `LEFT JOIN` makes sure every row from the table left to the operator is retained in the result even if there's no matching row in the table right of it.

To export it put the query in parenthesis (important!) and let it follow the copy command:

```
COPY (SELECT t1.formalid,
             t3.nametext,
             t2.typetext,
             t1.textdata
             FROM table1 t1
                  LEFT JOIN table2 t2
                            ON t2.nameid = t1.id
                  LEFT JOIN table2 t3
                            ON t3.id = t1.id)
      TO '<path to the output file>'
      WITH FORMAT csv;
```

Change `<path to the output file>` to the path of the file you want the output to go into. The path must be on the server machine, i.e. the machine the Postgres service runs on, not the client machine and it must be write accessible for the user the Postgres service runs under.

There are some more options, that let you toggle headers, define the encoding, etc., have a look at [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-copy.html) to learn more about them.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot and indeed results in what I expected. another question, if I should make a whole new question no biggie. I was wondering if you could point me in the right direction for an additional step to this. I want a new column that has a TRUE/FALSE value depending on if two tables have the same data. For instance, if t1.formalid is located in t4, then in the resulting exported query it would have a new column 'unique' with TRUE for that entry not existing, and FALSE for it existing. Since this results from in an UPDATE with an IF this would necessitate a temporary table right?

Comment: @tbleader: Sounds like a new question.